# MariaDB: Why 'order by null' command doesn't remain 'Using filesort' on the Extra(Explain)

Tags: mariadb

I wonder an one sql command.

I'm using MariaDB 10.0.33

Table schema is like

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| site_cd         | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| site_fair_cd    | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| detail_cnt      | varchar(10)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name            | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| little_title    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| info_text       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| yoyaku          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| charge          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| person          | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price           | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| remainder       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date            | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| time            | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| start_sec       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| end_sec         | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| url             | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| crwl_date       | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| regist          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Index is like

```
+----------------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                      | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| table_name                 |          1 | crwl_date_index |            1 | crwl_date       | A         |       22237 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
```

SQL is two pattern.

First is as below.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE DATE(crwl_date) AS date,count(*) AS cnt
    FROM  table_name
    WHERE  crwl_date >= '2018-03-20'
      AND  crwl_date <  '2018-03-28'
    GROUP BY  DATE(crwl_date);
+------+-------------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                      | type  | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                                     |
+------+-------------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table_name                 | range | crwl_date_index | crwl_date_index | 9       | NULL | 43958 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Second is as below.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE DATE(crwl_date) AS date,count(*) AS cnt
    FROM  table_name
    WHERE  crwl_date >= '2018-03-20'
      AND  crwl_date <  '2018-03-28'
    GROUP BY  DATE(crwl_date)
    ORDER BY  NULL;
+------+-------------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table                      | type  | possible_keys   | key             | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                     |
+------+-------------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | table_name                 | range | crwl_date_index | crwl_date_index | 9       | NULL | 43958 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary |
+------+-------------+----------------------------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Second SQL includes 'ORDER BY NULL'. So 'Using filesort' is gone.

I can't understand why this has happened. Please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL and MariaDB have a feature that when you have `GROUP BY` without `ORDER BY`, then the ordering is done using the group by list. So, your first query runs as if it was:

```
SELECT 
---
GROUP BY DATE(crwl_date)
ORDER BY DATE(crwl_date) ;
```

When you explicitly add `ORDER BY NULL`, then that feature is disabled and no `ORDER BY` is used, so no filesort needed.

This is explained in [MySQL `ORDER BY` optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> By default, MySQL sorts all `GROUP BY col1, col2, ...` queries as if you specified `ORDER BY col1, col2, ...` in the query as well. If you include an explicit `ORDER BY` clause that contains the same column list, MySQL optimizes it away without any speed penalty, although the sorting still occurs.
>
> If a query includes `GROUP BY` but you want to avoid the overhead of sorting the result, you can suppress sorting by specifying `ORDER BY NULL`. For example:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO foo
> SELECT a, COUNT(*) FROM bar GROUP BY a ORDER BY NULL;
> ```

---

There are also some [improvements in MariaDB versions 10.1 and 10.2 regarding `ORDER BY`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/improvements-to-order-by/), although I think they are not relevant to your case.

In any case, it would best if you upgraded to the latest stable release (10.2.13 currently).